# Can't translate QComboBox's "Cancel" and "Done" button in iOs

Tags: ios, iphone, qt, qcombobox

I use Qt to make a multilanguage app in iOS.

and i use "*.ts" and "*.qm" file to translate text.

the QComboBox in ios has 2 buttons can't be translate.

the ts file need a classname, but i can't found this 2 words in any class from qt source.

[image]

Comment: How did you create the Buttons "Done", "Cancel" ?

Comment: Did you create them in qt Designer?

Comment: the QComboBox was auto show "Done" and "Cancel" button in iOS .is use ios style self.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on your code

Comment: create a new project, add a dialog, add a qcombobox on dialog.  run project in ios.  when click combobox, the buttons will show.  no need any code......

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show what you have attempted so far, and why it is failing. Also, the example you post must be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the Cancel and Done translations are in the Qt translation.  I think you need one QTranslator for your app string and a second for the Qt library strings.

The qt_*.qm files are in your Qt directory someplace.

For example, to switch to German you would need to switch two translators:

- myapp_de.qm
- qt_de.qm

https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application

See loadLanguage() is setting two QTranslators, one for app, and one for Qt.

```
    // Called every time, when a menu entry of the language menu is called
void MainWindow::slotLanguageChanged(QAction* action)
{
 if(0 != action) {
  // load the language dependant on the action content
  loadLanguage(action->data().toString());
  setWindowIcon(action->icon());
 }
}

void switchTranslator(QTranslator& translator, const QString& filename)
{
 // remove the old translator
 qApp->removeTranslator(&translator);

 // load the new translator
 if(translator.load(filename))
  qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
}

void MainWindow::loadLanguage(const QString& rLanguage)
{
 if(m_currLang != rLanguage) {
  m_currLang = rLanguage;
  QLocale locale = QLocale(m_currLang);
  QLocale::setDefault(locale);
  QString languageName = QLocale::languageToString(locale.language());
  switchTranslator(m_translator, QString("TranslationExample_%1.qm").arg(rLanguage));
  switchTranslator(m_translatorQt, QString("qt_%1.qm").arg(rLanguage));
  ui.statusBar->showMessage(tr("Current Language changed to %1").arg(languageName));
 }
}
```